# Phonegap Storage Methods. Are they different

Tags: android, ios, cordova

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

This is the link to the official guide. But I am very very confused. The first half of the page describes the Storage method and then seemingly lower down on the page the Local Storage method is described.

Are these two things distinctly different. I know there is a size limit of 5Mb for a Local Storage implementation, but is there a similar size limit on a SQLite storage method. Or am I completely wrong and these two things are describing the two sides of the same coin?

Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The local storage is key value paired methodology for storing data where as SQLite storage uses an actual database structure to store complex data.

However there is one more option jStorage.